# Uncaught ArgumentCountError

Tags: plugins

I'm trying to fix a friend's wordpress website (as the closest thing she has to a vaguely techie friend :) ).  She updated a plugin as instructed to do when she logged on to administer the site (she can't remember what the plugin was called), then suddenly was unable to access website admin and got a critical error white page.  I tried renaming the plugins folder but that didn't change anything (I've renamed it back to plugins). I figured out how to get the error to log by editing the wp-config.php file, and the error that comes up is as follows:-

```
**Fatal error**: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function WP_Widget::__construct(), 0 passed in /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 62 and at least 2 expected in /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php:163 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php(62): WP_Widget->__construct() #1 /var/www/wp-includes/widgets.php(115): WP_Widget_Factory->register('tecblogger_abou...') #2 /var/www/wp-content/themes/tecblogger/inc/widgets/about_widget.php(7): register_widget('tecblogger_abou...') #3 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): tecblogger_about_load_widget('') #4 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #5 /var/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #6 /var/www/wp-includes/widgets.php(1858): do_action('widgets_init') #7 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): wp_widgets_init('') #8 /var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #9 /var/www/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #10 /var/www/wp-settings.php(643): do_action('init') #11 /var/www/wp-config.php(100): require_once('/var/www/wp-set...') #12 /var/www/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/var/www/wp-con...') #13 /var/www/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/var/www/wp-loa...') #14 /var/www/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/var/www/wp-adm...') #15 {main} thrown in **/var/www/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php** on line 163
```

Needless to say this is meaningless to me but the fact that I've managed to get some info back from the website feels like progress.  I'm asking here because it seems the most knowledgeable place to ask and I'm hoping somebody will understand this and be able to give me some instruction I can follow.  I obviously have access to the site via file system (from the hosting website, GoDaddy) so I can delete, rename and edit as necessary.

[Later note: On looking at the Tecblogger theme files, I found an "about_widget.php" which has the line:

```
- parent::__construct( 'tecblogger_about_widget', __('Tecblogger : About Me', 'tecblogger'), $widget_ops, $control_ops )
```

[On looking at the themes website, I've noticed that this Tecblogger theme is a really old theme (2018) and in fact there's a warning on the themes website that it may not work now. Perhaps that's the problem?]

Any help greatly appreciated.  TIA.

Comment: Welcome to WordPress StackExchange! In your theme there is somewhere a `class tecblogger_about` or something similar. Within that class you might find a line like `parent::__construct( … )`. If you update your question with the full statement up to the closing `);`, we _might_ be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I found an "about_widget.php" which has the line:-

parent::__construct( 'tecblogger_about_widget', __('Tecblogger : About Me', 'tecblogger'), $widget_ops, $control_ops )

On looking at the themes website, I've noticed that this Tecblogger theme is a really old theme (2018) and in fact there's a warning on the themes website that it may not work now.  Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: That looks correct. The error message suggests that the constructor is called with incomplete arguments, but that doesn't seem to be the case. You might have better luck asking the theme's [support](https://www.themepoints.com/contact/). But the theme hasn't seen an update for almost seven years, so I wouldn't expect too much.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth just deleting all the themes from the wp-content/themes folder, sticking a fresh copy of default 2023 or something in there on its own and seeing if the website fires up that way?  At least if I can get the website up and running the aesthetics can be sorted out in due course.

Comment: Ah, didn't need anything so drastic, I just renamed the Tecblogger theme folder to something else, the website has reverted to default and progress is now posssible.  Thanks for your help fuxia!